# what does it mean to host on 10.0.0.0 IP address for flask webserver

Tags: python, flask, networking

My knowledge of networking is limited. So I might state the question wrong:

So as I understand that the code `app.run(host='0.0.0.0'`. Meaning you host on all of your current machine IP address.

So I suppose that hosting on `app.run(host='10.0.0.0'` mean that I am hosting on all IP address from range: `10.0.0.1 ~ 10.255.255.255`.

But when I try to host on 10.0.0.0. The other machine on the same network cannot detect my flask service. (my machine ip address is 10.0.0.70, so I think 10.0.0.0 cover my machine ip address)

So there is flawed in my understanding, what is it?
1/ you can't host flask on 10.0.0.0
2/ 10.0.0.0 is not really the range of ip from 10.0.0.1 to 10.255.255.255
3/ something else.

An

Answer (score 0):

0.0.0.0 - 0.255.255.255 is reserved for software.

10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255 is reserved for local addresses.

If you use 10.?.?.? then you have to enter the address to your address bar.